# Viewing 2 monitors on 1 monitor

Tags: display, screen-sharing

My boss has three monitors.  2 are connected to a PC, and one is an iMac running 10.7.  He is running Windows on his iMac and has extended the desktops of all three of them, but he would like to view both PC monitors on the iMac screen - maybe one monitor on the left and one on the right.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused, is he using two machines or one?

Comment: The question is confusing. First you say the iMac is running OS X 10.7, then you say it's running Windows. Also, how do you "extend the desktop to all three of them" if the standalone monitors are connected to the PC? Also, wouldn't the text be very squished and hard to read if you combined the output of two monitors onto a single screen and scaled it appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to view Windows desktop screens from another machine is to use "RDP". This is a protocol for sharing screens and is a Microsoft standard.

You can get RDP clients for Mac OSX, install one and give it the IP address of the Windows machine. You may need to enable remote sharing on the Windows machine and you should note that, when connected this way, Windows disconnects the local monitors so that you can only work one way or the other at any one time.

You might need to allow "Remote Assistance" on the Windows machine, search for it in the start menu, it is one of the tabs on "System Properties".

It is also possible to work the other way round with the Mac screen(s) being viewed on Windows. This is normally done using something called "VNC". The Mac needs a "VNC Server" and the Windows machine needs a "VNC Client". These are easily found via a search and very easy to install and set up.